# Can occasional intervals of physical exercise increase focus and therefore intelligence?

Tags: exercise

Somewhere I heard that doing some physical exercise can help de stress and focus on other work. Is this true? What are the reasons behind this?

Comment: It helps maintain focus because you don't get tired as quickly during work or  whatever it is your doing, but this is just my opinion based on my experience. Its helped me push through alot (hours, no days) of mind numbing paperwork that I'd rather get done and get back to the funner or more enjoyable side of work. - Like @Craig said :)

Answer (score 1):

Exercise will not increase intelligence. However, I can tell you from my own expierience that if you are a consistent exerciser that it definitely increases the conditioner's focus. When I started lifting in high school, I noticed my grades increased drastically and my attention span during class was much longer. Sure, some could call it coincidental but I noticed when I took a 2 month break my grades dropped a little lower. Is that a coincidence? Not only that, but side effects of exercise consist of:
Longer life span(extends it 5-10 years)
Optimism
Self-Confidence and courage
Self-respect
Respect from others
Strengthens bones
Strengthens muscles
Improves fitness level
Sense of self-accomplishment
Lets you contact your inner self(better meditation)
Opens new doors

Answer (score 0):

If you were to swap **occasional** for **regular**, then this earlier [answer of mine](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19550/why-do-so-many-fitness-websites-still-reference-somatotypes/24869#24869) may answer you question:

"There have also been numerous studies that show a [neurobiological effect / benefit of physical exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurobiological_effects_of_physical_exercise), to quote wikipedia:"

> People who regularly participate in aerobic exercise have greater
>   scores on neuropsychological function and performance tests. Examples
>   of aerobic exercise that produce these changes are running, jogging,
>   brisk walking, swimming, and cycling. Exercise intensity and duration
>   are positively correlated with the release of neurotrophic factors and
>   the magnitude of nearly all forms of exercise-induced behavioral and
>   neural plasticity; consequently, more pronounced improvements in
>   measures of neuropsychological performance are observed in endurance
>   athletes as compared to recreational athletes or sedentary
>   individuals. Aerobic exercise is also a potent long-term
>   antidepressant and a short-term euphoriant; consequently, consistent
>   exercise has also been shown to produce general improvements in mood
>   and self-esteem in all individuals.